# push down div when hidden div is shown using jQuery and css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 5 buttons all contain some different data, I want when u click a button should show its hidden data, and push down the div below it:

```js
$(".Datanewpost").click(function() {
  $(this).find(".data").toggle();
});
```

```css
.data {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data-main">

  <div class="Datanewpost">
    Data 1
    <div class="data"> Lorem ipsum to roboczy tekst używany do celów projektowych, zwykle do prezentacji kroju pisma, kompozycji, układu kolumn, wyglądu składu, typografii itd./div>
    </div>
    <div class="Datanewpost">
      Data 2
      <div class="data"> Lorem ipsum to roboczy tekst używany do celów projektowych, zwykle do prezentacji kroju pisma, kompozycji, układu kolumn, wyglądu składu, typografii itd.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="Datanewpost">
      Data 3
      <div class="data"> Lorem ipsum to roboczy tekst używany do celów projektowych, zwykle do prezentacji kroju pisma, kompozycji, układu kolumn, wyglądu składu, typografii itd./div>
      </div>
      <div class="Datanewpost">
        Data 4
        <div class="data"> Lorem ipsum to roboczy tekst używany do celów projektowych, zwykle do prezentacji kroju pisma, kompozycji, układu kolumn, wyglądu składu, typografii itd.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="Datanewpost">
        Data 5
        <div class="data"> Lorem ipsum to roboczy tekst używany do celów projektowych, zwykle do prezentacji kroju pisma, kompozycji, układu kolumn, wyglądu składu, typografii itd.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Right now its just toggle elements without pushing them down, what do I need to change to get what I want?

Comment: You have typos in your html.  If you look at the tidy html in the snippet, some of the closing divs are `/div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had some missing `<` when closing divs

```js
$(".Datanewpost").click(function() {
  $(this).find(".data").toggle();
});
```

```css
.data {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data-main">
  <div class="Datanewpost">
    Data 1
    <div class="data"> Lorem ipsum to roboczy tekst używany do celów projektowych, zwykle do prezentacji kroju pisma, kompozycji, układu kolumn, wyglądu składu, typografii itd.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Datanewpost">
    Data 2
    <div class="data"> Lorem ipsum to roboczy tekst używany do celów projektowych, zwykle do prezentacji kroju pisma, kompozycji, układu kolumn, wyglądu składu, typografii itd.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Datanewpost">
    Data 3
    <div class="data"> Lorem ipsum to roboczy tekst używany do celów projektowych, zwykle do prezentacji kroju pisma, kompozycji, układu kolumn, wyglądu składu, typografii itd.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Datanewpost">
    Data 4
    <div class="data"> Lorem ipsum to roboczy tekst używany do celów projektowych, zwykle do prezentacji kroju pisma, kompozycji, układu kolumn, wyglądu składu, typografii itd.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Datanewpost">
    Data 5
    <div class="data"> Lorem ipsum to roboczy tekst używany do celów projektowych, zwykle do prezentacji kroju pisma, kompozycji, układu kolumn, wyglądu składu, typografii itd.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After adjusting your markup, we'll be using the `slideToggle` method to accomplish your task:

```js
   
 

$(".Datanewpost").click(function() {
  $(this).find(".data").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.data {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="data-main">
  <div class="Datanewpost">
    Data 1
    <div class="data"> Lorem ipsum to roboczy tekst używany do celów projektowych, zwykle do prezentacji kroju pisma, kompozycji, układu kolumn, wyglądu składu, typografii itd.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Datanewpost">
    Data 2
    <div class="data"> Lorem ipsum to roboczy tekst używany do celów projektowych, zwykle do prezentacji kroju pisma, kompozycji, układu kolumn, wyglądu składu, typografii itd.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="Datanewpost">
    Data 3
    <div class="data"> Lorem ipsum to roboczy tekst używany do celów projektowych, zwykle do prezentacji kroju pisma, kompozycji, układu kolumn, wyglądu składu, typografii itd.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Datanewpost">
    Data 4
    <div class="data"> Lorem ipsum to roboczy tekst używany do celów projektowych, zwykle do prezentacji kroju pisma, kompozycji, układu kolumn, wyglądu składu, typografii itd.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="Datanewpost">
    Data 5
    <div class="data"> Lorem ipsum to roboczy tekst używany do celów projektowych, zwykle do prezentacji kroju pisma, kompozycji, układu kolumn, wyglądu składu, typografii itd.</div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> [Learn more](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) about `slideToggle` method.

Hope I pushed you further.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes just have a look on it

```js
window.onload=function()
{
var btn=document.getElementsByClassName('Datanewpost');
for(var i=0;i<btn.length;i++)
{
 btn[i].onclick=function()
 {
   var data=document.getElementsByClassName('data');
   for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
   data[i].style.maxHeight="0px";
   this.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight="1000px";
   this.nextElementSibling.style.transition="0.4s ease";
   }
 
 }
}
```

```css
.data {
  max-height:0px;
  overflow:hidden;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data-main">

  <div class="Datanewpost">
    Data 1
   </div>
    <div class="data"> Lorem ipsum to roboczy tekst używany do celów projektowych, zwykle do prezentacji kroju pisma, kompozycji, układu kolumn, wyglądu składu, typografii itd.</div>
    
    <div class="Datanewpost">
      Data 2
    </div>  
      <div class="data"> Lorem ipsum to roboczy tekst używany do celów projektowych, zwykle do prezentacji kroju pisma, kompozycji, układu kolumn, wyglądu składu, typografii itd.</div>
   
    <div class="Datanewpost">
      Data 3
     </div>
      <div class="data"> Lorem ipsum to roboczy tekst używany do celów projektowych, zwykle do prezentacji kroju pisma, kompozycji, układu kolumn, wyglądu składu, typografii itd.</div>
     
      <div class="Datanewpost">
        Data 4
      </div>
        <div class="data"> Lorem ipsum to roboczy tekst używany do celów projektowych, zwykle do prezentacji kroju pisma, kompozycji, układu kolumn, wyglądu składu, typografii itd.</div>
      
      <div class="Datanewpost">
        Data 5
      </div>
        <div class="data"> Lorem ipsum to roboczy tekst używany do celów projektowych, zwykle do prezentacji kroju pisma, kompozycji, układu kolumn, wyglądu składu, typografii itd.</div>
     
    </div>
```